# Error connecting while the pSQL from clickhouse

Tags: postgresql, odbc, clickhouse

I have ~/.odbc.ini

```
[DEFAULT]
Driver = myconnection

[myconnection]
Description         = PostgreSQL connection to my_db
Driver              = PostgreSQL Unicode
Database            = staging-**-db
Servername          = **.**.**.**
UserName            = staging-**-user
Password            = ******
Port                = 5432
Protocol            = 11
ReadOnly            = No
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ConnSettings        =
```

I an trying to make a dictionary

```
CREATE DICTIONARY psql_temp4
(
    id UInt64,
    app String,
    name String
)
PRIMARY KEY id
SOURCE(ODBC(CONNECTION_STRING 'DSN=myconnection' TABLE 'django_migrations_copy'))
LIFETIME(MIN 300 MAX 360)
LAYOUT(HASHED())
```

The error I get is

```
ode: 86, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Received error from remote server /identifier_quote?connection_string=DSN%3Dmyconnection. HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Error getting identifier quote style from ODBC 'Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Connection attempt failed: Connection:Not applicable
Server:Not applicable
===========================
ODBC Diagnostic record #1:
===========================
SQLSTATE = IM002
Native Error Code = 0
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

OS version 
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

What could be the reason ?

Comment: you should find .so file for postgresql ODBC file and add `DRIVER = /full/path/to/portres/odbc/driver.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ch needs full path to driver

```
/etc/odbc.ini 
[mysqlconn] 
DRIVER = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so
```

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/odbc/